# Mongodb + Java Drivers. Search by date range

Tags: java, mongodb, date

This is my first shot at using Mongodb with the java drivers.  I can query the database via command line using javascript and the Date() object, however, I am having trouble using the driver.  Based on my query, can anybody see what the problem is?  Thanks

```
            Date current = new Date();
            DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("messages");

            BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("created_on", new BasicDBObject("$gte", new Date(current.getYear(), current.getMonth(), current.getDate())).
                    append("created_on", new BasicDBObject("$lt", new Date(current.getYear(), current.getMonth() - 1, current.getDate()))));

            System.out.println("Query: " + query);


            DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query);
```

> Query: { "created_on" : { "$gte" : { "$date" :
>   "2012-12-06T05:00:00.000Z"} , "created_on" : { "$lt" : { "$date" :
>   "2012-11-06T05:00:00.000Z"}}}}

P.S. In case it is not obvious, I'm trying to find all of the records within the last month.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seems like you are constructing the query wrong. Please try the below one:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("created_on", //
                      new BasicDBObject("$gte", new DateTime().toDate()).append("$lt", new DateTime().toDate()));
```

`Datetime` object is a library which simplies date manipulation in java. You can check that out.
http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Also morphia is a nice java object-document-mapper (ODM) framework for working with mongodb through java driver. It simplifies querying through java.

https://github.com/jmkgreen/morphia

Answer (score 3):

Based on the query that was output, you are looking for a document with a field `created_on` that also has a child named `created_on`. I assume no such document exists. In other words, you query is not correctly formed.

Your query object should look like this:

```
BasicDBObject dateRange = new BasicDBObject ("$gte", new Date(current.getYear(), current.getMonth(), current.getDate());
dateRange.put("$lt", new Date(current.getYear(), current.getMonth() - 1, current.getDate());

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("created_on", dateRange);
```

Also, as a sidebar, you probably should avoid using the three-argument constructor of the `java.util.Date` class, as it is deprecated. When working with dates in the MongoDB Java driver, I typically use the `java.util.Calendar` class, and its `getTime()` method.

Comment: I'm still not getting any results.  Here is the new printed query: db.messages.find({ "created_on" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2012-11-06T05:00:00.000Z"} , "$lt" : { "$date" : "2012-12-06T05:00:00.000Z"}}});

Comment: ..also, I know there is data there.  This query works from the terminal..db.messages.find({created_on: {$gte: new Date(2012,11,6), $lt: new Date(2012,12,6)}});

Comment: The javascript Date object has a 0-indexed month field. new Date(2012,11,6) is actually Dec 6, 2012. Not sure if this changes anything, but it might be why you are getting results for the console query, but not the driver.

Comment: Right, I realize that.  That is why I'm subtracting a month from my Java Driver query.  Also, I switched the date ranges around in the query that you provided because they were backwards.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used the Java driver for mongo before, but it seems that the query you have created is not correct.

```
Query: { "created_on" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2012-12-06T05:00:00.000Z"} , "created_on" : { "$lt" : { "$date" : "2012-11-06T05:00:00.000Z"}}}}
```

The query should in fact end up looking like:

```
Query: { "created_on" : {$gte: start, $lt: end}}
```

Where start and end are dates.  It seems like the second time you refer to "created_on" is unnecessary and in fact might be breaking your query.

NOTE: I have not had the chance to test out this theory, but I am working from http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/ which seems to be very relevant to the question at hand.

Comment: I agree with you.  For some reason, the java driver creates a strange query that doesn't seem to work.  I have temporarily given up on this.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Jodatime lib is very userful, Please make use of DateTimeZone.UTC for timezone parameter of DateTime.  Once you set timezone, you will get accurate results. Try this

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    //get current year,month & day using Calender
    int year=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int monthNumber=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int dateNumber=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    monthNumber+=1;


    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("dateCreated",new BasicDBObject("$gte", new DateTime(year, monthNumber, dateNumber, 0, 0,DateTimeZone.UTC).toDate()).append("$lte",new DateTime(year, monthNumber, dateNumber, 23, 59,DateTimeZone.UTC).toDate()));

    System.out.println("formed query: "+query);

    DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);
    while(cursor.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println("found doc in given time range: "+cursor.next().toString());
    }
```