# Mongodb query on date has no results (java)

Tags: java, mongodb, date

My mongodb query is not returning any results and I can't spot why.

Here is the relevant contents of my data:

```
> db.reports.find({},{endDate:1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5182882ae4b032c67674c494"), "endDate" : ISODate("2013-05-02T15:37:11.032Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51828859e4b032c67674c495"), "endDate" : ISODate("2013-05-02T15:37:57.749Z") }
```

So I have two entries with dates 2013-05-02 15:37:11-57

I want to find all entries with a date less than or equal to that latest date, but I get no results using this query:

```
db.reports.find({ "endDate" : { "$lte" : { "$date" : "2013-05-02T15:37:11.032Z"}}},{endDate:1})
```

I am generating the query in java using:

```
BasicDBObject oldReportSelector = (BasicDBObject) BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
    .add("endDate", 
        BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().add("$lte",myDate).get())
    .get();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit to add:
myDate is calculated using:

```
Date endDate = new Date()
Date myDate = new Date(endDate.getTime()-(interval*quantityArchivedReports));
```

Currently interval = 86400000 and quantityArchivedReports = 4

Comment: What is that `myDate` variable you are using in your java code? What's the class and value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752616/mongodb-java-drivers-search-by-date-range

Comment: Pawel:I've added the extra information. Pangea: Thanks for the link. While I could change to use DateTime, I'd rather understand why what I have is not working. Mongodb claims to support java.util.Date natively so there must be something wrong with my query

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not getting anything in the shell is that you are not using the date format the shell expects.  Try changing your query to:

```
> db.reports.find({ "endDate" : { "$lte" : new Date("2013-05-02T15:37:11.032Z")}})

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5182882ae4b032c67674c494"), "endDate" : ISODate("2013-05-02T15:37:11.032Z") }
```

You can then use the shell to verify if your code has actually generated a correct date to get back any data or not.