# Fetch mongo documents based on date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

We are inserting mongo documents with identifier and there is a subarray within the documents.

```
insert 1 :

db.test.insert(
   {
        "companyId" : "123",
        "persons" : [
                {
                        "joiningDate" : NumberLong("1431674741623"),
                         "name" : "Rajesh"
                }
        ],

})

insert 2 :

db.test.insert(
   {
        "companyId" : "123",
        "persons" : [
                {
                        "joiningDate" : NumberLong("1431674741653"),
                         "name" : "Rahul"
                }
        ],

})
```

I would like to retreive the company details based on the company id and merge the persons into one array list,  and sort the persons based on the joining date.

Currently I am able to retreive the data using QueryBuilder but I am unable to sort the person based on the date.I can use java comparator to do the same , but I am looking out if there is any API from mongo db java driver which can be used to get the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Why 'joiningDate' data type is NumberLong??

Comment: @gypsyCoder   it should be epoch time :)

Comment: @gypsyCoder: This is too an issue I have noticed , the dates are being set as NumberLong in mongo Db .In java code it is a part of util package constructed using a long in ms value.

Comment: @Amz are you using java.util.Date() ??

Comment: @gypsyCoder: yeah I am ,

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752616/mongodb-java-drivers-search-by-date-range

Answer (score 4):

you should use [mongo aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) like first [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) `persons` array and then sort `persons.joiningDate` and then `group with push` as below :

```
db.test.aggregate({
  "$match": {
    "companyId": "123" // match companyId
  }
}, {
  "$unwind": "$persons" //unwind person array
}, {
  "$sort": {
    "persons.joiningDate": -1 //sort joining date
  }
}, {
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$companyId",
    "persons": {
      "$push": "$persons" //push all sorted data into persons
    }
  }
}).pretty()
```

For converting this code into java use [mongo java aggregation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/getting-started/quick-tour/) as

```
// unwind  persons
DBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$persons");
// create  pipeline operations, with the $match companyId
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("companyId", "123"));
// sort persons by joining date 
DBObject sortDates = new BasicDBObject("$sort", new BasicDBObject("persons.joiningDate", -1)); // -1 and 1 descending or ascending resp.
// Now the $group operation  
DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", "$companyId");
groupFields.put("persons", new BasicDBObject("$push", "$persons"));
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);
// run aggregation
List < DBObject > pipeline = Arrays.asList(match, unwind,sortDates, group);
AggregationOutput output = test.aggregate(pipeline);
for(DBObject result: output.results()) {
  System.out.println(result);
}
```