# How to use Spark MongoDB-Connector with conditional query ？

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

Recently  I  try  to use MongoDB-Connector from the [Official documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/current/java/read-from-mongodb/) 

`JavaMongoRDD<Document> rdd = MongoSpark.load(jsc);`

but the  demo  will load  all the data  from my collection ,
I just want to  run  this  command   in  my  java or scala code 

 `db.pointer.find({"inserttime":{$lt:new Date(2018,0,4,7,0,10),$gte:new Date(2018,0,4,7,0,0)}},{"inserttime":1,})`

I know  I can use `RDD.filter()`  to get the data I want.

but  it will query all data at the first time ,That's not what I want.
Thanks in advance .

EDIT:
Did it provided  any  method with condition query to  reduce the result data when query .

like JDBC:

`find(and(eq("status", "A"),or(lt("qty", 30), regex("item", "^p"))));`

Comment: I mean  it will query all data from my collection ，it will Increase MongoDB's Reading Pressure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/current/java/aggregation/) uses aggregations to filter data at the database level, so you can do the same.

```
// the following example was not tested

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$lt", new Date(2018,0,4,7,0,10);
query.put("$gte", new Date(2018,0,4,7,0,0));

JavaMongoRDD<Document> aggregatedRdd = rdd.withPipeline(singletonList(query));
```

Date range query trick came from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13752955/5761558)

Comment: it will query all data from my collection ,That's not what I want.  I  just  wanted to reduce the data size   when  query .

Comment: @HbnKing How do you know? The point of `withPipeline(singletonList(query))` is to filter on the specified query before data is loaded into spark's memory.

Comment: thanks a lot  , when  use `withPipeline` ..  each  stage must stay within the 100 megabyte memory limit   in  your demo    ?